# jQuery Sliders for slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, sliders

Which is a good jQuery slider for moving a div element.

I have come across [coda slider](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/#4) and [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)

But neither of these uses jQuery1.3 and continuous auto-scrolls, which are my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/anythingslider-a-great-jquery-slider-plugin/

Comment: This is the perfect thing, I was looking for. Better than anything I found via googling for 15 min! SO rocks!